# Visual Studio Code Coverage: Empty results generated: no binaries were instrumented

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, xunit

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 version `17.6.5`. For certain repositories, I cannot utilize Code Coverage. I have tried the following:

- Every option for Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects (x86, x64, ARM64, Auto)
- Deleting .suo files
- Reinstalled Visual Studio
- Repaired Visual Studio
- Disabling both debug and release optimization
- Toggling the preview feature `Code Coverage native static instrumentation`

The complete error is:
`Empty results generated: no binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings.`

The tests did run. I can't find what the required binaries are though. The code coverage was not excluded through custom settings, as a colleague can run code coverage on all the repositories.

I am using the following NuGet packages in my test project:

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 17.6.3
- Moq 4.18.4
- FluentAssertions 6.11.0
- xunit 2.5.0
- xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.5.0

They are all the latest versions.

I have only installed the `.NET desktop development` package from the Visual Studio Installer.
The problematic repos are all .NET 6, upgraded from .NET Core 3.1, as are the repos that are fine, so I don't think that's the issue. What are other steps I can take to try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague who was successful in running code coverage did this from version 17.0.21. When I downgraded from 17.6.5 to 17.2.17, my code coverage tool ran again.